# ATI (AMD) HD7750 proprietary drivers flickers and falls back to VESA

Tags: gnome, ati, xorg, 14.04

I have recently upgraded my working x86_64 13.10 system to 14.04.  However, when using the proprietory AMD drivers, Gnome (not tested with Unity) flickers and falls back to VESA.

The graphics hardware is:

```
damien@damien-desktop:~$ lspci | grep ati
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750 / R7 250E]
02:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
```

The following errors can be seen in the xorg log:

```
damien@damien-desktop:~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   140.108] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   140.795] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[   140.795] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[   140.795] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
```

The offending file can be found, but is in the wrong spot:

```
damien@damien-desktop:~$ find /usr | grep 'fglrx_dri.so'
/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/fglrx_dri.so
/usr/lib/fglrx/dri/fglrx_dri.so
/usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so
```

The driver reports itself as follows:

```
damien@damien-desktop:~$ dmesg | grep -i ati
[    3.942522] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[    3.977331] fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.006431] input: HDA ATI SB Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input15
[    4.006518] input: HDA ATI SB Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input14
[    4.006627] input: HDA ATI SB Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input13
[    4.006667] input: HDA ATI SB Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input12
[    4.006839] input: HDA ATI SB Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input11
[    4.006945] input: HDA ATI SB Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input10
[    4.007023] input: HDA ATI SB Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input9
[    4.007075] input: HDA ATI SB Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input8
[    4.015326] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input21
[    4.015410] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input20
[    4.015472] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input19
[    4.015854] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input18
[    4.016008] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input17
[    4.016132] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input16
```

The first few lines of the xorg.log which shows the versions of the drivers and servers are:

```
damien@damien-desktop:~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | head -150
[   140.073] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[   140.073] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   140.073] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   140.073] Current Operating System: Linux damien-desktop 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64
[   140.073] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=66cfd47c-d1eb-4f45-9a4b-0a6ea079fe90 ro quiet splash nomdmonddf nomdmonisw vt.handoff=7
[   140.073] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:36:29PM
[   140.073] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   140.073] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[   140.073]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   140.073] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   140.074] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Apr 24 06:28:36 2014
[   140.074] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   140.074] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   140.074] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   140.074] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   140.074] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   140.074] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   140.074] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   140.074] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   140.074] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   140.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   140.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   140.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   140.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   140.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   140.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   140.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   140.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   140.074] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   140.074]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   140.074] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   140.074] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   140.074] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   140.074] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f6fc74e5d60
[   140.074] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   140.074]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   140.074]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[   140.074]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[   140.074]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[   140.075] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 1002:683f:174b:e213 rev 0, Mem @ 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xfde80000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000de00/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension Present
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   140.075] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[   140.076] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[   140.076] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[   140.076] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   140.076] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   140.076] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[   140.076]    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
[   140.076] Loading extension GLX
[   140.076] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[   140.076] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[   140.076] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[   140.076] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[   140.076] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[   140.076] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   140.076] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[   140.076] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[   140.090] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[   140.090]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.35.5
[   140.090]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   140.090] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[   140.090] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[   140.090] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[   140.090] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[   140.090]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.35.5
[   140.090] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   140.090] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[   140.090] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   140.090]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 7.3.0
[   140.090]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   140.090]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   140.090] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[   140.091] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[   140.091] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   140.091]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 7.3.0
[   140.091]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   140.091]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   140.091] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   140.092] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   140.092] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   140.092]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[   140.092]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   140.092]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   140.092] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   140.092] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   140.092] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   140.092]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[   140.092]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   140.092]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   140.092] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   140.092] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   140.092] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   140.092]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[   140.092]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   140.092]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   140.092] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:13.35.5
[   140.092] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPORTED-13.35.1005               
[   140.092] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Mar 12 2014 10:32:23
[   140.092] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI Radeon chipsets:
    ATI Radeon Mobility X600 (M24) 3150 (PCIE), ATI FireMV 2400 (PCI),
    ATI Radeon Mobility X300 (M24) 3152 (PCIE),
    ATI FireGL M24 GL 3154 (PCIE), ATI FireMV 2400 3155 (PCI),
    ATI Radeon X600 (RV380) 3E50 (PCIE),
    ATI FireGL V3200 (RV380) 3E54 (PCIE), ATI Radeon IGP320 (A3) 4136,
    ATI Radeon IGP330/340/350 (A4) 4137, ATI Radeon 9500 AD (AGP),
    ATI Radeon 9500 AE (AGP), ATI Radeon 9600TX AF (AGP),
    ATI FireGL Z1 AG (AGP), ATI Radeon 9800SE AH (AGP),
    ATI Radeon 9800 AI (AGP), ATI Radeon 9800 AJ (AGP),
    ATI FireGL X2 AK (AGP), ATI Radeon 9600 AP (AGP),
    ATI Radeon 9600SE AQ (AGP), ATI Radeon 9600XT AR (AGP),
    ATI Radeon 9600 AS (AGP), ATI FireGL T2 AT (AGP), ATI Radeon 9650,
    ATI FireGL RV360 AV (AGP), ATI Radeon 7000 IGP (A4+) 4237,
    ATI Radeon 8500 AIW BB (AGP), ATI Radeon IGP320M (U1) 4336,
    ATI Radeon IGP330M/340M/350M (U2) 4337,
```

Comment: Did you added `LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib64/modules/dri` somewhere? Also, why you have the 32 bit version of fglrx drivers with a 64-bit system? Did you tried removing the drivers?